# How to fix modal is not a function?

Tags: jquery, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

i'm pretty sure that i have sort the .js files in the right way,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

then i call the modal like this

```
$("#save").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        url : "{{url('modul/store/')}}",
        type : "post",
        data : $('#form-modul').serialize(),
        success : function(){
          $('#modal-modul').modal('hide');
          table.ajax.reload();
        },
      })
    })
```

it's working fine in the **native** php, but after i use **laravel** then the error appears.
Any help or suggest?

Comment: can you tell me which type of error you get? and tell me what you written in routes.php

Comment: Can you please upload the code of the mode,l how you have integrated it with Laravel and the a copy of the error message that you are getting?This will give us the information that we need in order to help solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
 $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'/getstore',
               data:'_token = <?php echo csrf_token() ?>',
               success:function(data) {
                 console.log("it is successed");
                  $("#msg").html(data.msg);
                  $('#modal-modul').modal('hide');

               }
            });
```

Add the following lines in app/Http/routes.php.

```
Route::post('/getstore','AjaxController@index');
```

Create AjaxController.php in this path app/Http/Controllers/

AjaxController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AjaxController extends Controller {
   public function index() {
      $msg = "This is a simple message.";
      return response()->json(array('msg'=> $msg), 200);
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but the concern is how to dismiss the modal itself by jquery

Comment: you want to hide modal after successful response of ajax

Comment: please check my answer and check your console you will get message in console.

Comment: of course, but i'm getting error (...).modal() is not a function if i put this $('#modal-modul').modal('hide');

Comment: never mind, couse i have found that my js having some conflict. that's why i'm getting this error, thank you before

Answer (score 0):

try to use css to hide modal.

```
$("#modal-modul").css("display", "none");
```

Comment: it would be the last option, if i can't solve it the right way, but thank you for your suggest